# How to change coordinate system?

Tags: draw.io, diagrams.net

Is it possible to change default coordinate system to be like classic Cartesian coordinate system? Basically I just need to flip Y axis direction. I didn't find such option in application settings. I will give you example what I want to achieve. I have line ("line 1" in the picutre). The coordinates of this line segment are (-100,-100) and (-200,-200). For this coordinates I expect the line segment will be located in the position of the "line 2" line segment.
[image]